# Grant password-less permission for specific script as specific user with sudo

Tags: debian, permissions, linux, sudo

I have a server running Debian Squeeze with the latest updates. I tried to set up the `sudoers` file to allow the user `www-data` execution of a specific shell-script as a specific user. I used `visudo` for this and added the line:

```
www-data ALL=(img) NOPASSWD: /path/to/script/imgsync.sh
```

Then I tried to call it as user www-data (I su-ed from root to www-data first):

```
sudo -u img /path/to/script/imgsync.sh
```

To my surprise, it still asks for a password:

```
[sudo] password for www-data:
```

I expected `NOPASSWD:` to take care of this?

What really puzzles me: I have another server with the same setup, where it works without password. Also, I have other similar permissions on the same server that also work without password.

I even added the line

```
Defaults:www-data       !authenticate
```

with visudo (just to test, I don't want this). Then, when I tried again, I got the (contradictory) error message:

> Sorry, user www-data is not allowed to execute
>   '/path/to/script/imgsync.sh' as img on servername.

How can I get make it execute without having to supply a password (and without giving any more rights to www-data)?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, nothing is wrong with the above setup. In my tests, the script encountered a directory where the user `img` lacked permissions, which caused the result as described.

While it all works now, I am still a bit unhappy about the unhelpful error message / behavior of `dash` (default non-login shell).

I'll leave the post, might be helpful to others.